Pool processing in python thows index out of range error
I am running the below simple code to access the global variable and manipulate the content using multi processing, but its giving list index out of range even though the indexed element is present
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool

testarr=[]
def initFunction(length=100000) :
    for i in range(0,length):
        print("*****"+str(i))
        testarr.append({"value":str(i),"flag":0})

def checkForEvenAtIndex(index=0):
    print(str(index))
    if int(testarr[index]["value"])%2==0:
        testarr[index]["flag"]=1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.time()
    #print(start)
    cpu = 4
    length =100000
    initFunction(length)
    with Pool(cpu) as pool:
        print(pool.map(checkForEvenAtIndex,range(0,length)))
    end = time.time()
    print('Total time taken *****'+str(end - start))

Exact error :
    if int(testarr[index]["value"])%2==0:
           ~~~~~~~^^^^^^^
IndexError: list index out of range

"""
Looks to be a lack of knowledge in python for me. I come from C++ background. Please assist. The exact index at which always gives the error is 93750 (this could be wrong. but after printing this one, it fails)
--------Modified the code to include Manager as per comments-----
import multiprocessing
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager
testarr=[]


class CustomManager(BaseManager):
    # nothing
    pass
def initFunction(arr,length=100000) :
    for i in range(0,length):
        print("*****"+str(i))
        arr.append({"value":str(i),"flag":0})

def checkForEvenAtIndex(sharedarr,index=0):
    print(str(index))
    if int(sharedarr[index]["value"])%2==0:
        sharedarr[index]["flag"]=1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.time()
    cpu = 4
    length =100
    processes = []
    #print(start)
    CustomManager.register('list',list)
    with CustomManager() as manager:
        sharedarr=manager.list()
        initFunction(sharedarr,length)
        for i in range(length):
            p = multiprocessing.Process(target=checkForEvenAtIndex, args=(sharedarr,i))
            processes.append(p)
        for p in processes:
            p.start()
        for p in processes:
            p.join()
    end = time.time()
    print('Total time taken *****'+str(end - start))

New Error :
line 18, in checkForEvenAtIndex
TypeError: 'AutoProxy[list]' object is not subscriptable


the main process puts items in the list it owns, then it spawns workers that have empty lists because the code in if __name__ == '__main__': only runs in the main process

The error occurs because in Python's multiprocessing, global variables like testarr are not shared across processes. You can use a Manager to create a shared list that all processes can access and modify.

@liaifat85. then what does it point to when execution ? Will using manager cause the GIL to come into picture ?

@AhmedAEK are you saying it creates empty copies of the variable testarr for each sub processes ?

each process has its own memory space, and all processes execute your script, but only the main one executes whatever is inside if __name__ == '__main__':

@liaifat85 added manager. new error

@AhmedAEK True, but even if all processes executed all of the code, they would still not share the variables. Each would just create their own set of variables.

What is causing the exception is that creating a managed list is a bit more involved than what you are doing. But there is no need for you to be doing this since there is already a subclass of multiprocessing.managers.BaseManager that has implemented this for you, namely multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager. You can create an instance of this manager with the call multiprocessing.Manager().
There is also a subtlety in using a managed list. In your case each element of your list is a dictionary and your code updates the dictionary with sharedarr[index]["flag"]=1. But this will not work with a managed list. When you create a managed list you are given a reference not to the actual list but rather to a proxy for the list. When you perform an operation (method call) on the list, the proxy object takes your request and sends it off the the process that the SyncManager has created and in which the actual list resides. But your code is not performing an operation on the list; it is performing an operation on an element of the list, i.e. the dictionary, and the actual list will not get updated. You need code such as:
def checkForEvenAtIndex(sharedarr, index=0):
    print(index)
    d = sharedarr[index] # get the dictionary
    if int(d["value"]) % 2 == 0:
        d["flag"] = 1 # update the dictionary
        sharedarr[index] = d # re-assign to the list

You are also creating an extremely large number of processes. For CPU-bound worker functions, creating more processes than the number of CPUs you have is counterproductive. For demo purposes we will reduce the number down to the number of CPUs you have. Note I have modified the code to be in closer conformance with the PEP8 Style Guide and to remove some other inefficiencies. You would be well-advised to review these changes:
import multiprocessing
import time

def init_function(arr, length=100000) :
    for i in range(0, length):
        #print("*****", i))
        arr.append({"value": str(i), "flag": 0})

def check_for_even_at_index(sharedarr, index=0):
    print(index)
    d = sharedarr[index] # get the dictionary
    if int(d["value"]) % 2 == 0:
        d["flag"] = 1 # update the dictionary
        sharedarr[index] = d # re-assign to the list

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.time()
    length = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    #print(start)
    with multiprocessing.Manager() as manager:
        sharedarr = manager.list()
        init_function(sharedarr, length)
        processes = [
            multiprocessing.Process(target=check_for_even_at_index, args=(sharedarr, i))
            for i in range(length)
        ]
        for p in processes:
            p.start()
        for p in processes:
            p.join()
        for item in sharedarr:
            print(item)
    end = time.time()
    print('Total time taken *****', end - start)

Prints:
0
2
1
3
7
6
5
4
{'value': '0', 'flag': 1}
{'value': '1', 'flag': 0}
{'value': '2', 'flag': 1}
{'value': '3', 'flag': 0}
{'value': '4', 'flag': 1}
{'value': '5', 'flag': 0}
{'value': '6', 'flag': 1}
{'value': '7', 'flag': 0}
Total time taken ***** 0.47028136253356934

If you had a much larger array and still wanted to limit the number of processes created, then you should use a multiprocessing pool:
import multiprocessing
import time
from functools import partial

def init_function(arr, length=100000) :
    for i in range(0, length):
        print("*****", i)
        arr.append({"value": str(i), "flag": 0})

def check_for_even_at_index(sharedarr, index=0):
    #print(index)
    d = sharedarr[index] # get the dictionary
    if int(d["value"]) % 2 == 0:
        d["flag"] = 1 # update the dictionary
        sharedarr[index] = d # re-assign to the list

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.time()
    length = 100
    pool_size = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    #print(start)
    with multiprocessing.Manager() as manager, \
    multiprocessing.Pool(pool_size) as pool:
        sharedarr = manager.list()
        init_function(sharedarr, length)
        worker = partial(check_for_even_at_index, sharedarr)
        pool.map(worker, range(length))
        for item in sharedarr[:5]:
            print(item)
        print('...')
        for item in sharedarr[-5:]:
            print(item)
    end = time.time()
    print('Total time taken *****', end - start)

Prints:
{'value': '0', 'flag': 1}
{'value': '1', 'flag': 0}
{'value': '2', 'flag': 1}
{'value': '3', 'flag': 0}
{'value': '4', 'flag': 1}
...
{'value': '95', 'flag': 0}
{'value': '96', 'flag': 1}
{'value': '97', 'flag': 0}
{'value': '98', 'flag': 1}
{'value': '99', 'flag': 0}
Total time taken ***** 0.4600529670715332

